# checkbox values won't show up on javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

On this case i try to test did checkbox values show up on client side.
When i run, the alert shows nothing. Please help me, thank you.

```
<div>
                <label name="finishing"class="col-sm-2 mb-3">&nbsp;&nbsp;Finishing</label>
                  <input type="checkbox" id="finishingnya" value="emboss">&nbsp;Emboss&nbsp;
                  <input type="checkbox" id="finishingnya" value="Hot_Print">&nbsp;Hot Print&nbsp;
                  <input type="checkbox" id="finishingnya" value="Cover_Tutup">&nbsp;Cover Tutup&nbsp;
                  <input type="checkbox" id="finishingnya" value="Sablon">&nbsp;Sablon&nbsp;
                  <input type="checkbox" id="finishingnya" value="Tanpa_Finishing">&nbsp;Tanpa Finishing
                  <br >
                  <button id="submit_finishing" type="button" onclick="cobaintest()" style="margin-left: 175px; margin-bottom: 10px;">Simpan Finishing</button>
                </div>

                <script>    
                    function cobaintest(){
                    var cekbok = document.getElementById('finishingnya');
                    var finishinghasil = "";
                       for(var i = 0; i < cekbok.length; i++){
                          if(cekbok[i].checked){
                              finishinghasil = finishinghasil + cekbok[i].value +", ";
                          }
                      }
                       alert(finishinghasil);
                  }
                </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't have more than one element with the same ID. try something like:

```js
function cobaintest() {
  let finishinghasil = [...document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]:checked')].map(el => el.value);
  console.log(finishinghasil.join(", "));
}
```

```html
<label name="finishing" class="col-sm-2 mb-3">Finishing</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" value="emboss"> Emboss </label>
<label><input type="checkbox" value="Hot_Print"> Hot Print </label>
<label><input type="checkbox" value="Cover_Tutup"> Cover Tutup </label>
<label><input type="checkbox" value="Sablon"> Sablon </label>
<label><input type="checkbox" value="Tanpa_Finishing"> Tanpa Finishing </label>
<hr>
<button id="submit_finishing" type="button" onclick="cobaintest()" style="margin-left: 175px; margin-bottom: 10px;">Simpan Finishing</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change id to class where you’ve assigned the same values to multiple ids. Change getElementById to getElementByClassName. Get element by id returns a single value while get element by class name or get element by tag name returns an array or node respectively.